# sas, proc export, version number, delete xlsx

Tags: sas

I have noticed that when I add new fields, I have to keep changing the version number on the proc export excel file. Is there SAS code I can run before this to delete that xlsx on the unix server? That would greatly help, therefore I would not need to keep on changing the version number in the file. Thanks for your help.

```
proc export DATA=OUT.REQ_1_1_19T1
            OUTFILE= "/server/project/users/myid/case/case_WORKING_DATA_V6.xlsx"
            DBMS=xlsx REPLACE ;
                        SHEET = "REQ_1_1";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this page: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245893.htm

Basically it just checks if the file exist and then delete it.